# Tomcat Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing, amazon-elb, internal-load-balancer

I using ELB load 2 EC2 run tomcat 8 server.

I using AB for test

```
ab -n 7000 -c 7000 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" http://mywebsite.com
```

I check log ELB right with 7000 requests sending (some request 503)

But, I check in log access tomcat only 5600 requests access.

=> Tomcat service temporarily unavailable

How I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Add acceptCount in Connector server.xml

Comment: <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" acceptCount="7000" redirectPort="8443"/>

Comment: This is my config. It is good?  <Connector  port="8080" 
                maxThreads="2000"
                maxIdleTime="30000"
                protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                connectionTimeout="200000"
                redirectPort="8443" 
                executor="tomcatThreadPool"
                maxConnections="-1"
                socket.appReadBufSize="20480"   
                socket.appWriteBufSize="20480"
                keepAliveTimeout="-1"
                acceptCount="7000"
    />

Comment: It don't working right. I think that may be due to server overload => tomcat temporary unavailable => response is 503. I guess that.

Comment: The connector acceptCount is point serversocketchannel backlog, tomcat default count is 100. So I think if the accept count increase, the accept connection queue will be increase.  Here is the java api abstract ServerSocketChannel bind(SocketAddress local, int backlog)
Binds the channel's socket to a local address and configures the socket to listen for connections.

Comment: I using maxConnections="-1" I think don't have limit connection

Comment: If you read the tomcat source code, you will know maxConnections and acceptCount are two different things, lol. But i still confuse why acceptCount did not work for you this time. If i have time i will simulate same environment as your's to identify this issue.

Comment: I using AWS EC2 1 CPC 3.7GB RAM, with 2 server you think we can process 7000 concurrency? Reason is if I set acceptCount="7000" but may be  resource server I have is not enough.

Comment: Yes, you are right, we don't know the resource server(your hardware) if can support so many TCP/IP requests in the socket queue. So we need test. I saw a article before who set the acceptCount=8192 in their server

Comment: When I check in VisualVM CPU 50%, JVM 30%. But I test with AB have 3000 request failed. You think why?

Comment: Can you check this file value in you VM? /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog